# tableView of tableViewController does not change according to its orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a class which is subclass of tableViewController. I am trying to rotate my table view. I implemented two methods :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft |
                                     UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This controller is named as rootViewController and part of appDelegate's method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rootViewController];
self.navigationController = navController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

where I have set rootViewController as navigationController and its rootViewController as my  rootViewController object.

I dunno if the two methods are sufficient to reload the table according to the orientation. Do I have to include any other methods? And I saw that (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: of my rootViewController is not called after rotation but shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: is called often even when it is not required. I saw a similar post and there they suggested to include [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: interfaceOrientation] but still it didn't work.

Comment: are you using iOS6? The methods you're mentioning are from <= iOS5. There's a new model for rotation in 6 and above and you need to implement both if you want backwards compatibility.

Comment: ah then you might want to remove the iphone-5 tag from your question as it only runs iOS6 and above and might cause confusion.

Comment: also whats the larger project set to do with orientation?

Comment: basically there is a set of servers listed in table view. When the orientation changes from portrait to landscape I need it to change the table view accordingly. should we manually change the table view height and width or if we reload will the controller change according to the window?

Comment: no, no need to manually change things. In Xcode, if you click on the project in the left hand section, then select the targets Summary, look for what the supported interface orientations are.

Comment: oh.. k k ..supported interface orientations for project are landscapeRight, landscapeLeft and portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you shouldn't need to manually change anything.
Question: is the tableView set as the view for the enclosing viewController?

Comment: No, I am using the TableViewController's subclass and using the table view which is provides by it. I am only setting windows rootviewcontroller as my created class's object

Comment: any way to share the project to see the problem in context?

Comment: I really did a stupid mistake and was searching the whole net and seeing all the discussions in stackoverflow finally found the mistake. Sorry for troubling you too.

Comment: Maybe add the fix as a comment to help anyone else looking for help?